# Rename "*.sample.js" files to "*.js" in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Currently, I'm working on a project where I need to git ignore my local config files. This means that if the user clones the repository, he would see `*.sample.js` files inside the config dir.
If the user executes `make config` the following script is executed.

```
config:     ##@Misc Create config files
            @cd src/backend/config
            @cp cache.sample.js cache.js
            @cp database.sample.js database.js
            @cp steam.sample.js steam.js
            @cp teamspeak.sample.js teamspeak.js
            @cp website.sample.js website.js
            @echo
```

This script basically removes the "sample" part from the file name. The above code needs to be modified when ever I add a new config file, which is not a practical thing.

I would like to convert this into a simple regex command like:

```sh
find -iname \*.sample.js -type f -exec rename -n 's/(.*sample\.js)/$1/' {} \;
```

This command doesn't work, at least on windows MINGW64 bash. I need a vanilla solution.

Comment: `find -iname \*.sample.js -type f -exec bash -c 'echo mv -v "${0/.sample/.js}" {} \;`

Comment: @Jetchisel Do I need to remove that echo part?

Comment: If you're ok with the output, then yes

Comment: The output is: `mv -v ./cache.js.js`

Comment: `find -iname \*.sample.js -type f -exec bash -c 'echo mv -v "${0/.sample}"' {} \;`

Comment: This command need a closing single quote after echo. Apart from that I get an error: 
 "mv: missing destination file operand after './cache.js'"

Comment: `find -iname \*.sample.js -type f -exec bash -c 'echo mv -v "$0" "${0/.sample}"' {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jetchisel for a working solution:

```sh
find -iname '*.sample.js' -type f -exec bash -c 'for f; do cp "$f" "${f/.sample}"; done' sh {} +
```

Bonus: why that last + sign?

That will process as many files as possible while avoiding arg_max
as opposed to \; which will process one file per -exec call

Comment: `'*.sample.js'` or  `\*.sample.js`